# Trouble Opening File in C

Tags: c, file, text, io

I am very new to programming (and this website) so thank you for your help and your patience. I am writing a function that counts the number of lines in a text file, but opening the file always returns NULL. I am (mostly) sure that the file is in my current working directory, however I have the same issue when I use an absolute path. I have looked at lots of sample code but cannot for the life of me find where I'm going wrong.

This is the code I wrote to test opening the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fileOpen(char *);

int main()
{
    printf("%d", fileOpen("My File.txt"));
    return 0;
}
int fileOpen(char *fileName) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName,"r");

    if (fp == NULL);
    return -1;

    if (fp != NULL);
    return 1;
}
```

This always returns -1.
Thank you again for any help you can give me,
-Ian

Comment: Also, it is easy to get the system to tell you why fopen failed: `if( fp == NULL ){ perror(fileName); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. You can run your program step-by-step and for example check the value of `fp` after `fopen`.

Comment: OT: the second `if (fp != NULL)` is pointless, because here `fp` is always different from `NULL`.

Comment: As you will be needing that file pointer, I suggest changing the function type to `FILE*` and simply `return fp;`. As it is, you lose that file pointer. Of course, you can't output it it with `printf` like you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here

```
if (fp == NULL);
        return -1;
```

What you are essentially saying to the compiler is

"If fp is null." As the ; acts to close that statement
Instead you should only have  a semicolon following the return -1; such that you are now saying

"If fp is null, return -1."

The semicolon acts to delimit full statements, not neccesarily just lines

```
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;
```